# How to play embedded videos(offline videos) or embed videos inside LibreOffice Impress

Tags: windows-7, libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

We are migrating from MS office to libre office and I would like to know if libre office Impress has a add on or option to embed offline videos. I have an existing powerpoint presentation with embedded videos that would play upon clicking on the slide. It does not seem to work with libre office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Insert -> Audio/Video**, you can find information on supported video formats [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/854/what-video-formats-does-libreoffice-impress-support/). More information can be found on official LibreOffice [wiki](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Audio_or_Video).